# Granting apps on Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm using Google API to open a file picker and select a file from Goolge Drive. It works but I've got a strange problem about application grants. If I load a file from Google Drive app, I can't select the files (it's gray) but if I upload the file from the web interface of Google Drive, then I can select the file. Can I do something to have the grant on those files? Is it a bug?

PS: I load the file on my phone via Google Drive app but opening the file via Dropbox because when I select "Upload" from Google Drive app I can't select a file browser app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is grayed out, this means that it doesn't not match one of the MimeTypes you provided when you configured the OpenFileDialog.  Only files that match those MimeTypes will be selectable.

This doesn't have anything to do with authorization.  The file picker is a privileged dialog that displays all of the user's files, since the picker is owned by the Google Drive API.

Comment: You're right. The problem is with MIME type. When I open a web uploaded file in the web interface I receive "unknown file" but when I open a file loaded via Google drive app I see the overview. Do you know how to avoid any manipulation of the file loaded from google drive apps?